# How do I remove Links from a Discord Webhook?

Tags: javascript, discord, embed

Im quite new to coding, currently im trying to edit Discord Webhooks via js to code Monitors.

Now I'm trying to remove something from the Embed. I'm looking through Codes and Commands but I can't find a solution for this.

In this Case:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf0x5.png)

the Webhook contains a Link. Everytime this Link comes up I want it to get wiped from the Embed.

I tried to do something with:

```
function FixEmbeds(embeds) {
embeds.forEach(function(part, idx) {
    //embeds[idx].footer = undefined;
```

but I'm not getting forward with this. Anyone that could point me the way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to remove the link portion but keep the title, remove `url` instead e.g:

```
delete embeds[idx].url
```